# Is there a way to assign a String object as a custom class instance?

Tags: java, reflection

Tried to extend from String class but it is final, hence looking for a way so that I can assign a String object as my custom class instance?

Example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public CustomString cString;
}

MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
Field field = myClass.getField("cString");
field.set(myClass, "TestValue");
```

Comment: No, but you could make your `CustomString` take a constructor that takes a `String`. What is `CustomString`?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish? This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Why use reflection for a public field you know the exact name of?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes I know, but thats not what I want. @chrylis this is not XY problem, I have shown the code above, I want after calling `field.set(Object, Object)` my cString becomes "TextValue"

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils it is a JSON reader using reflection to set the field values of my class. In fact it uses a loop to loop through all the fields. I just simplified the code to show the core part using `getField(String)`.

Comment: You could take a setter approach via convention. IOW, provide setters with the convention `setFieldName`, then use reflection to get those setters and call them with the string value.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Thanks you mean if I have declared a `setFieldName(String)` method then calling `field.set(Object, Object)` can set the value to my custom string?

Comment: No, I'm saying that instead of grabbing them by their name and setting the value (since it's a "custom string" type), use reflection to get those setters.For example, prepend `set` to the pascal-cased field name and get the method needed to set the value. Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

If you must do this with reflection, how about using methods instead of fields. Specifically, try using a setter convention like so:

```
class MyClass {
    private CustomString customString = new CustomString();

    public CustomString getCustomString() {
        return customString;
    }

    public String getCustomStringValue() {
        return customString.getValue();
    }

    public void setCustomString(String customString) {
        this.customString.setValue(customString);
    }
}

class CustomString {
    private String value;

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    String fieldName = "customstring";
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    Method[] methods = myClass.getClass().getMethods();
    for(Method method : methods) {
        String name = method.getName();
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("set" + fieldName) {
            method.invoke(myClass, "Hello");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(myClass.getCustomStringValue());
}
```

This way you can still use the field names but allow the field to be set by a method which can be arbitrarily interesting.

Comment: The question is asked to set the `CustomString` field, not construct a `CustomString` object.

Comment: @DeanXu, it's just an example.The only reason why I construct the object explicitly is to have something to work with; they'll already have that in their code. Nonetheless, they have to set a "custom string" object with a string value which won't work without an interface between it.

Comment: @DeanXu, refactored the code to to be more in line with the question though still not intended to be perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the field with a little encapsulation. If the field's type is `CustomString`, we transform the value to `CustomString` object. Here is the complete codde:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Q47027440 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    Field field = MyClass.class.getField("str");
    set(field, myClass, "TestValue");
    System.out.println(myClass.str.actual);
  }

  public static void set(Field field, Object obj, Object value)
      throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    if (field.getType() == CustomString.class && value instanceof String) {
      CustomString cs = CustomString.class.newInstance();
      cs.actual = (String) value;
      value = cs;
    }
    field.set(obj, value);
  }

  public static class CustomString {
    public String actual;
  }

  public static class MyClass {
    public CustomString str;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code. Code only answers are against the guidelines for answering..

Comment: @CKing This code actual only contains one method with 6 lines. It's too simple to explain.

Comment: I was trying to help you out so that your efforts don't go to waste. But if you insist, feel free to leave your answer without any explanation and watch it get ignored :)

Comment: @CKing Thank you for your suggestion. And I will add explanation later.